# Grep XML string on specific tag name and replace text value

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, grep

How can I `grep` an XML string for element `<name>` with the text `property1` and then replace the next `<value>` element's text content?

```
<property>
  <name>property1</name>
  <value>7200</value>
</property>
```

Expected View after desired value is 1000:

```
<property>
  <name>property1</name>
  <value>1000</value>
</property>
```

Comment: You're implying that there are multiple `<name>` elements in your XML. Please show a representative sample of your complete XML document. It would also go down much better if you appeared to have made an effort to solve this yourself: it's bad form to attempt to get work done for free if you can't approach it yourself: do some reading.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Please *always test* anything that you submit as an answer. If you are certain that something is correct but cannot test then you must say so in your post.

Comment: @Ravinder: You should have realised that the OP showed only part of the XML data: they ask to `grep` a particular `<name>` element. If you believe that XML tools would be better then you should say so. *"I deleted since xml tools would be better for this kind of question"* That's a bizarre idea. Why do you delete chunks of XML?

Comment: A huge majority of your questions have zero or negative votes. Please try to understand why and correct it. You are likely to be blocked if you persist.

Comment: @Ravinder: You shouldn't apologise: it's simply expected that you are accountable for anything you post, and you should take care of what you say. I'm not sure `xmlstarlet` will help a lot, but by all means give it a try. It is best to fall back on the RFC documents that define XML, XPath, XSLT etc. A Google search will find them for you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short-order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

It's XML, so `grep` is the wrong tool for the job. Regular expressions in general are not contextual, and XML is.

Use a parser:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $xml = XML::Twig -> new -> parse (\*DATA);
my $matching_property = $xml -> get_xpath('//property/name[string()="property1"]/..',0);

$matching_property -> first_child('value') -> set_text('1000');

$xml -> set_pretty_print ('indented_a');
$xml -> print;

__DATA__
<property>
<name>property1</name>
<value>7200</value>
</property>
```

This uses `xpath` which is similar to regular expressions, except that it is context sensitive, and 'works' with XML metadata.

Comment: I know that you prefer to put spaces around the indirection operator, but it makes your code much more difficult to read for me, and likely many others. The operator `->` is already longer than most, and to turn it into a *four-character* gap before the next operand is too much: it becomes as big as the usual four indentation spaces. You've even hit the right margin of the SO code block, which is bad news.